# python subprocess grep returns zero

Tags: python, grep, subprocess, python-2.6

I'm trying to count the number of times the string OW appears in a file with the following scrip,

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("grewp Ow file.txt | wc -l", shell=True)
```

but it always returns the correct answer followed by zero

```
>>> subprocess.call("grep OW production_run.gro | wc -l", shell=True)
2638
0
>>>
```

and when I try to declare a variable with it, it stores 0.
Does anyone here have any idea of why that's happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Python's docs about subprocess.call

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then
>   return the returncode attribute.

Try `check_output` instead

Answer (score 0):

based on [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) `subprocess.check_output` :

> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

Thus you can use this:

```
count = int(subprocess.check_output("grewp Ow file.txt | wc -l", shell=True))
```